# A session once created only get expires

Tags: session, cookies, session-cookies

**"A session once created only get expires"**
I mean a session is created for every user. But when the user closes the browser the session cookie gets destroyed and so the session (which is even now in the session store) becomes of no use.
These sessions keeps on accumulating in the session store until they expires themselves.
Please correct me if i am wrong.
Also is there a way to clear the session when the user closes the browser?

Thanks for help

Comment: Session expiration is typically 20-30 minutes, so I can't see how this would be a problem.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch  session expire time and cookie expire time are always same or they can be different. Well there is no point in the two being different..but i mean do we need to set the time for each seperately or they point to the same thing? thanks